# Can a child component be rendered in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I have now entered vue.
The code in vuetify uses nested components. In my code, when I try to nest it, only PARENT component is mounted.
what's the reason? How do I render CHILD component?

=======================my code=======================

```
<div id="app">
    <parent>
        <child></child>
    </parent>
</div>

<script>
    Vue.component('parent', {
        template: "<div class='parent'>PARENT</div>",
        mounted: function(){
            console.log("PARENT MOUNTED");
        }
    })
    Vue.component('child', {
        template: "<div class='child'>CHILD</div>",
        mounted: function(){
            console.log("CHILD MOUNTED");
        }
    })

    new Vue({
        el: "#app"
    })
</script>
```

console: PARENT MOUNTED

page: PARENT

======================vuetify code example========================

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-form v-model="valid">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="name"
        :rules="nameRules"
        :counter="10"
        label="Name"
        required
      ></v-text-field>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="email"
        :rules="emailRules"
        label="E-mail"
        required
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [component slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html).

In the updated code below, I just inserted a `<slot></slot>` inside the parent component in order for the child component to be rendered when used as a content of the parent component.

```js
    Vue.component('parent', {
        template: "<div class='parent'><slot></slot></div>",
        mounted: function(){
            console.log("PARENT MOUNTED");
        }
    })
    Vue.component('child', {
        template: "<div class='child'>CHILD</div>",
        mounted: function(){
            console.log("CHILD MOUNTED");
        }
    })

    new Vue({
        el: "#app"
    })
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <parent>
        <child></child>
    </parent>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it answer your question? please mark it as answer.